# Why am I getting child count update has encountered a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m on JBoss Dev Studio?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, apache-camel, redhat, jboss-developer-studio

When I try to debug and check the variables I get this error.

An internal error occurred during: "child count update".
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.logicalstructures.JavaStructureErrorValue cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core.IJavaObject

[image]

```
package com.optum.propel.service;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;

import com.optum.propel.commons.handler.BaseHandler;

public class Kafka_Consumer extends BaseHandler {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      String temp = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

    System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody().toString());
    System.out.println("From Kafka_Consumer:");
 }

}
```

Comment: Please share some of your code. Currently, this is not really solvable...

Comment: Please put that code into the question and not into a comment

Comment: I get the error at line "System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody().toString())". When debugging If I want to see what's on exchange variable. It throws the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Why not break the command [1] into 4 commands, assigning each call to a variable, and try/catch for exceptions to see what's going wrong?

[1] System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody().toString())